# Dynamic Linq: "Nullable object must have a value." on .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dynamic-linq

I have the following dynamic LINQ running without error on .NET Core 3.1.

```
query = query.GroupJoin(ParsingConfig.DefaultEFCore21,
                                detailObject,
                                "new { it.ExternalDataId2.Value AS I0}",
                                "new { Id AS I0}",
                                "new (outer AS A, inner AS B)");

query = query.SelectMany("B.DefaultIfEmpty()",
                         "new { source.A.Id AS Id,source.A.ExternalDataId2 AS ExternalDataId2,detail.Title AS ExternalData2Ref_Title,detail.Id AS ExternalData2Ref_Id}",
                         "source",
                         "detail");

query.ToDynamicListAsync();
```

I am porting my application to .NET 6.0 and have this error: *Nullable object must have a value.*

I tried removing "ParsingConfig" without solving the problem.
**Using SQL Profiler I saw that the query is executed**.

Full exception stacktrace:

```
Message: 
Test method FrameworkTests.DataLayer.FindTests.FindValueExternal threw exception: 
NTSFramework.DataLayer.DataLayerException: Errore generico di repository Nullable object must have a value.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

  Stack Trace: 
lambda_method559(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
DynamicEnumerableAsyncExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IEnumerable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
DynamicEnumerableAsyncExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IEnumerable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
BaseDataLayer.FindValuesAsync[TModel](FindValuesOptions findOptions) line 866
```

Changing the SelectMany as below no longer generates the error, but it's not the result I need:

```
query = query.SelectMany("B.DefaultIfEmpty()",
                     "new { source.A.Id AS Id,source.A.ExternalDataId2 AS ExternalDataId2,detail As ExternalData2Ref}",
                     "source",
                     "detail");
```

Comment: It has something to do with nullable properties, try removing `.Value` from `it.ExternalDataId2.Value`

Comment: Tried it, doesn't solve the problem. I have added more information. The problem seems to be in the SelectMany.

Comment: Add exception  callstack.

Comment: callstack added

Comment: did you try ```, detail != null ? detail.Title : string.Empty AS ExternalData2Ref_Title, ...```

Comment: It works! If you write a reply I will accept it!

Comment: @PaoloCrociati: I don't have Dynamic LINQ at hand, can you try the null-propagation function ```np()```? Instead of ```detail != null ? detail.Title : string.Empty``` try ```np(detail.Title)``` please.

Comment: @GWimpassinger Just tried it. It works.
The strange thing is that with .NET Core 3.1 it was not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from your `B.DefaultIfEmpty()` in your `SelectMany` expression. If the join does not yield any Bs your `detail` entity is `null` and you cannot dereference `detail.Title` or `detail.Id`.

You can either explicitly check for null and instead of just `detail.Title` you have to write`detail != null ? detail.Title : string.Empty AS ExternalData2Ref_Title`. Or you may use the Dynamic LINQ null propagating function `np()` and write `np(detail.Title)`.

In your code it should look like this (I assumed `detail.Id` is of type `int`):

```
query = query.SelectMany("B.DefaultIfEmpty()",
                     "new { source.A.Id AS Id,source.A.ExternalDataId2 AS ExternalDataId2, np(detail.Title) AS ExternalData2Ref_Title, detail != null ? detail.Id : 0 AS ExternalData2Ref_Id}",
                     "source",
                     "detail");
```